# Condição no Where SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho um *SELECT* com diversos *LEFT JOIN*, porém eu preciso considerar todos esses *LEFT JOIN* em algumas condições, já em outra condição eu preciso desconsiderar um *JOIN* feito.

> Como exemplo segue:

```
SELECT *
      FROM    
              TabelaTotal TT
LEFT JOIN   Client Cli              ON Cli.FKTT      = TT.Id 
LEFT JOIN   Tabela1 CN              ON CN.FK_Cli     = Cli.ID
LEFT JOIN    Produto Pr             ON Tabela1.ID    = Pr.FK_Tabela1
WHERE  
  --Condição considera todos os JOINS   
  and  
  (
   ( CT.Name <> 'A' and 
     Pr.QTD > 0 and  
   ) 
   --Condição que eu preciso desconsiderar o Relacionamento com a Tabela Produto     
    OR 
   ( CT.Name = 'A'
   )
  )
--Como fazer a condição CT.Name = 'A' desconsiderar o LEFT JOIN da tabela Produto
--LEFT JOIN    Produto Pr             ON Tabela1.ID    = Pr.FK_Tabela1
```

Comment: O LEFT JOIN já permite desconsiderar a relação! Você quer pegar somente onde a relação não é válida? É isso?

Comment: Eu quero fazer o relacionamento com a tabela Produto só quanto CT.Name <> 'A' 
Caso CT.Name = 'A' eu quero fazer o mesmo select porém quero desconsiderar o relacionamento com a tabela Produto, usando o LEFT ele retorna valores, quero que nem faça o  relacionamento com Produto

Comment: Primeiramente , não vejo nenhuma tabela renomeada como  `CT`, não esta clara a pergunta, os seus `LEFT JOIN` retornará todos os dados dessas tabelas e o seu `WHERE` faz o filtro onde  `(CT.Name <> 'A' and      Pr.QTD > 0 and )` or `(CT.Name = 'A')` , qual problema aqui?

Answer (score 1):

Para você desconsiderar **de fato** o JOIN, só consigo enxergar o uso do **UNION**.
Pode parecer estranho, a princípio, mas você consegue trabalhar com dois universos completamente distintos em termos de consulta.

E não é algo necessariamente ruim. Às vezes é mais simples pensar em operações como união, diferença ou interseção, pois podemos associar o problema a ser resolvido com teoria de conjuntos.

[Referência](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql)

Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM    
    TabelaTotal TT
    LEFT JOIN   Client Cli              ON Cli.FKTT      = TT.Id 
    LEFT JOIN   Tabela1 CN              ON CN.FK_Cli     = Cli.ID
    LEFT JOIN    Produto Pr             ON Tabela1.ID    = Pr.FK_Tabela1
WHERE  
( 
    CT.Name <> 'A' and 
    Pr.QTD > 0 and  
) 

UNION   


SELECT * FROM    
    TabelaTotal TT
    LEFT JOIN   Client Cli              ON Cli.FKTT      = TT.Id 
    LEFT JOIN   Tabela1 CN              ON CN.FK_Cli     = Cli.ID 
WHERE
    CT.Name = 'A'
```

PS: Demais detalhes da query foram omitidos.

Answer (score 0):

Eu colocaria a parte comum numa string padrão em tempo de design e adicionaria ou não a parte variável em tempo de execução.

```
sqldefault = SELECT * FROM    
TabelaTotal TT
LEFT JOIN   Client Cli              ON Cli.FKTT      = TT.Id 
LEFT JOIN   Tabela1 CN              ON CN.FK_Cli     = Cli.ID
/* variavel1 */ 
WHERE  
( 
   CT.Name <> 'A' 
   /* variavel2 */ 
)
```

Em tempo de execução o programa carrega a SQLDEFAULT para executar.

Verificar a condição, se ela não existir executa a SQLDEFAULT como está e segue. Senão altero a VARIAVEL1 na string SQLDEFAULT por

```
LEFT JOIN    Produto Pr             ON Tabela1.ID    = Pr.FK_Tabela1
```

e a variavel2 por

```
 Pr.QTD > 0
```

executa e segue.

Preciso desta SQLDEFAULT para poder limpa-la em outra condição. O sistema sempre parte da condição padrão e depois acrescenta ou não outras condições.

Answer (score 0):

você pode fazer uso da condição EXISTS.

```
SELECT *
FROM TabelaTotal TT
LEFT JOIN Client Cli ON TT.Id = Cli.FKTT
LEFT JOIN Tabela1 CN ON Cli.ID = CN.FK_Cli
WHERE  
    CT.Name = 'A' OR
    EXISTS (SELECT FK_Tabela1 FROM Produto Pr WHERE Pr.FK_Tabela1 = CN.ID AND Pr.QTD > 0)
```

Quanto a desempenho, você pode olhar o seguinte artigo:

[NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)